# Overlapped data when amend values of variables in shell script ubuntu 9.04 for ARM

Tags: shell, initialization, ubuntu-9.04

I created a shell script in `/etc/init.d/` to start/stop my application. The script is based on a skeleton script file which was originally located in `/etc/init.d`. This script imports variables from the `xxx.conf` configuration file.

```
# Read configuration variable file if it is present
[ -r /etc/xxx.conf ] && . /etc/xxx.conf
```

When assigning each imported variable and printing out the value with echo, it works well.

```
local A
A=$imported1
#print out exactly actual value of imported1
echo $A
local B
B=$imported2
#print out exactly actual value of imported1
echo $B
local C
C=$imported3
#print out exactly actual value of imported3
echo $C
```

However, when amending A, B, and C into a new string or even amending `imported1`, `imported2`, and `imported3` into a new string, these values will overlap each other.

```
local D
D="$A $B $C"
#print out value is overlap string of A,B and C instead of 'A B C'
echo $D
D="$imported1 $imported2 $imported3" 
#print out value is overlap string of imported1 ,imported2  and 
#imported3,as same as result when do echo "$A $B $C"
echo $D
```

How can I amend these imported variables correctly?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give specific examples of actual overlap results along with the original data. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you might have some control characters hidden in your variables. Probably a carriage return, which moves the cursor to the start of the line when you print it to a terminal.

You can make a carriage return many different ways -- this example will use `echo -e "\r"`:

```
A="$(echo -en 'A LONG WORD\r')"
B="$(echo -en 'short\r')"
```

Just like in your example, printing them individually will *look* like they only contain letters:

```
$ echo $A
A LONG WORD
$ echo $B
shorter
```

But if you print them together, the later one overlaps the earlier one:

```
$ echo "$A $B"
 short WORD
```

You can see the carriage return if you look at the output with `less`, `od -a`, or anything that doesn't interpret that control character to move the cursor.

Comment: and the solution is `dos2unix file1 file2 file3 .... ` AND stop using Windows editor/ftp/other. Good luck to all.